# compare as numeric value. unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix

So I am trying to test a few things coding in bash. As a n00b I am having some problems with the basics and how irritating it can get using shell dealing with numbers.

```
if $((echo $?)) > 0 ;then 
  echo "there is an error"; 
else
  echo "it passed"; 
fi
```

the error I get is :
bash: echo 0: syntax error in expression (error token is "0")

I tried without the echo and I get:
bash: ./0: Permission denied

so I am a bit confused what the shell is trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: If possible, don't even bother with `$?`. If `cmd` is the command that set the value of `$?`, you can just use `if cmd; then echo "it passed"; else echo "there is an error"; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole arithmetic evaluation must be within double parentheses:

```
if (($? > 0)) ;then 
  echo "there is an error"; 
else
  echo "it passed"; 
fi
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I would really appreciate it why we don't have $(($? > 0)) but (($? > 0)) instead. When do I need to have the $ sign?  For example I need echo $(($(ls | wc -l) / 3)) to see 1/3 of the number of files in the directory.Thanks again for the response.

Comment: Because `$((expression))` is the syntax for _arithmetic expansion_, not _arithmetic evaluation_, which is what you want for an `if` command as in your snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
OUT=$?
if [ $OUT -eq 0 ];then
   echo "OK!"
else
   echo "NOT OK!"
fi
```